# Change the default behaviour of NullValue in a DataSet

Tags: visual-studio-2010, linq, dataset

I have used the .Net MySQL connector to import a Dataset of a MySQL schema into Visual Studio.

Visual Studio has generated a `*.xsd` file for me with a visual representation of the tables, and fields within those tables in my schema.

I am then running queries against these tables using LINQ.

By default, the `NullValue` property of every field in every table is set to (Throw exception). What this means in practice is that if I apply criteria to any column which contains null values in a query, an Exception is thrown when I try to enumerate through the results as shown below:

[image: Exception]

The easy way to fix this is to change the NullValue property of that particular column to either `(Null)` or `(Empty)`, but I have a lot of columns in a lot of tables and changing all of these one at a time is a pain. I can't use the Shift key to select all columns either, as the `(Null)` and `(Empty)` values only apply to reference types and nullable value types, so if, for example, my selection contains a single integer, none of the properties will get updated.

Is there an option in Visual Studio to change the default behaviour of the NullValue property on a column in a DataTable across the board?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. In *Solution Explorer*, right-click on your .xsd file
2. Select *"Open With..."*
3. Choose *"XML (Text) Editor"*
4. Find a field you've already set to *"(Empty)"* or whatever you want as your "default" value and review of the syntax of the **`msprop:nullValue`** such as `msprop:nullValue="_empty"`
5. Use text *Search-and-Replace* (*CTRL+H* by default) to modify the rest of your nullable field XML tags in the file.  One way to do this is to find a standard column tag and add to it.  For example, find `msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInTable` and replace it with `msprop:nullValue="_empty" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInTable`
6. After you are done making replacements, ensure sure you only have one instance of the `msprop:nullValue` attribute per column or you'll have a DataSet syntax error
7. *Save* the file and close it
8. Double click on your .xsd so it opens in the XSD designer and then *Save* it to ensure you have no syntax errors and the designer.cs files are updated.